# UIApplicationDelegate methods not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unity-game-engine, uiapplicationdelegate

I am trying to create a plugin for region monitoring. Region Monitoring is starting fine but the function didfinishlaunching and didrecievelocalnotification are not being evoked. I am not sure why this is happening.

regionMonitoring.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


    @interface RegionMonitoringPlugin : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
    {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
    }

    -(void)enterRegionNotify;
    -(void)leaveRegionNotify;
    -(void)startMonitor:(float)latitude longitude:(float)longitude radius:(float)raduis;

    @end
```

regionMonitoring.mm

```
#import "RegionMonitoringPlugin.h"

@implementation RegionMonitoringPlugin

- (id) init
{
    //if ( init == [super init]){
    if (locationManager==nil){
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
    {
        [self enterRegionNotify];
    }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
    {
        [self leaveRegionNotify];
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)regionwithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Location error %@, %@", error, @"Fill in the reason here");
    }

-(void)leaveRegionNotify
{
    NSLog(@"Starting region monitoring - check point 3");

    UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    note.alertBody= @"Region Left"; // ToAsk: What should be displayed
    note.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:note];
    [note release];

}


-(void)enterRegionNotify
{
    UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    note.alertBody= @"Region Left"; //ToAsk: what should be displayed ? 
    note.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:note];
    [note release];

}

-(void)startMonitor:(float)latitude longitude:(float)longitude radius:(float)radius
{ 
    NSLog(@"Starting region monitoring - check point 2");
    [self leaveRegionNotify];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D home;
    home.latitude = latitude;
    home.longitude = longitude;
    CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:home radius:radius identifier:@"region"];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [region release];    
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Starting region monitoring - checkpoint 4");

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Region Monitor Notification" message:notification.alertBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
        [alertView show]; 
        [alertView release];
    } 
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      NSLog(@"Test");
    return TRUE;
}


@end


extern "C" {
        static RegionMonitoringPlugin *regionMonitor;

        // Unity callable function to start region monitoring
        BOOL _startRegionMonitoring(float m_latitude,float m_longitude, float m_radius)
        {

            NSLog(@"Starting region monitoring");
            if (![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] || ![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled] )
                return NO;

            if (regionMonitor == nil){
                regionMonitor = [[RegionMonitoringPlugin alloc]  init] ;
            }
            [regionMonitor startMonitor:m_latitude longitude:m_longitude radius:m_radius];
            return YES;

        }
}
```

Unity Code for plugin : RegionMonitorMediater.h

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class RegionMonitoringMediator {

    /*Interface to native implementation */
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool _startRegionMonitoring (float m_latitude,float m_longitude, float m_radius);

    public static bool startRegionMonitoring (float latitude,float longitude, float radius)
    {
         /*Call plugin only when running on real device*/
        if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor)
            return _startRegionMonitoring ( latitude , longitude , radius);
        else return false;

    }
}
```

Calling region monitor

OnPress event I do

```
bool startedRM = RegionMonitoringMediator.startRegionMonitoring(77.0f,28.0f,10.0f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `UIApplicationDelegate` allowed per app. When Unity3D builds your application for iPhone player a class `AppController` is generated which acts as interface.

This class is the place for inserting your code to call `RegionMonitoringPlugin`.

Comment: thanks kay. I noticed that AppController was passing on the notification to Unity. So I used NotificationServices class in unity to handle the notifications. However I have another question I realized even the location manager events are not being called swell any clue on that ? thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't used it so far.

Answer (score 0):

`init` should include a call to super at its start:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // initialize everything else
    }
    return self;
}
```

note that we used assignment (`=`) operator, and not comparison (`==`) operator.

Comment: Um, I think you meant 'self' as the lvalue of the assignment and in the `return`.

Comment: @KenThomases - most embarrassing typo for a long time... fixed, thanks.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet : I placed in the correction but still the functions are not being called do you see another issue.